# Paginating a model with attributes from multiple Arrays

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination, will-paginate, kaminari

I have four types of Rawscores I want to display together in a paginated table.

The code looks like:

```
@facebook_scores_today = Rawscore.where(:channel_string => "Facebook", :project => @project, :created_at.gt => Time.now.beginning_of_day)

@youtube_scores_today = Rawscore.where(:channel_string => "Youtube", :project => @project, :created_at.gt => Time.now.beginning_of_day)

@twitter_scores_today = Rawscore.where(:channel_string => "Twitter", :project => @project, :created_at.gt => Time.now.beginning_of_day)

@influence_scores_today = Rawscore.where(:channel_string => "Influence", :project => @project, :created_at.gt => Time.now.beginning_of_day)
```

Where Rawscore has a Hash with multiple values as atributes for table depending on `:channel_string`.

How should I go about this? Any gems that could help "will_paginate" or "kaminari" ?

Update ( Here is my Rawscore model)

```
class Rawscore
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps::Created #for created_at field

  belongs_to :channel
  belongs_to :project
  field :values, type: Hash
  validates :values, :presence => true

end
```

I want to display the keys-values for the :values Hash in the Rawscore model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to the question lies in using WillPaginate::Collection to create your own pagination structure.

Here is the rubydoc link: http://rubydoc.info/github/mislav/will_paginate/frames

Answer (score 1):

Kaminari can paginate arrays, but it's not efficient because Active Record will instantiated all retrieved records (I.e if you have 10000 records and want to show only 100, there will be 10000 AR objects in memory)

```
Kaminari.paginate_array(my_array_object).page(params[:page]).per(10)
```

Instead you can consider joining your queries and paginate with query

```
scores_today = Rawscore.where(
  :channel_string => ["Facebook", "Youtube", "Twitter", "Influence"], 
  :project => @project, :created_at.gt => Time.now.beginning_of_day
).page(params[:page])
```

Comment: I need to show one attribute from each type of Rawscore. How do I achieve that in view?

Comment: All the attributes are in the Hash of Rawscore model. How do I display them?

Comment: Please update your question with the code where you try display models. I don't understand what you want.